# Regex: Delete special characters from the content of a html tag

Tags: notepad++, regex

good day. I have this meta html tag:

`<meta name="keywords" content="'N Uitdagende reis in, die innerlike wêreld van 'n meganiese wese "/>`

I want to delete all special characters such as `[,']` which are found between `" "`

I made a good regex, the only problem is that I must press REPLACE ALL several times so as to delete all those special characters:

SEARCH: `<meta name="keywords" content=".*?\K[',](.*?)("/>)`

REPLACE BY: `\1\2\3`

Does anyone know a much better and faster solution?

Answer (score 1):

SEARCH: `(?:<meta name="keywords" content="|\G(?!^)).*?\K[',]+(?=.*?"/>)`

REPLACE BY: `LEAVE EMPTY`

- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>